# Storing image to Public folder Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to save an image to a folder in my laravel application.

I'm getting the error:

> fopen(F:\blog\public/usr-data/photos): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Here's my laravel controller which is writing to this folder.

```
$error          = false;
$absolutedir    = public_path();
$dir            = '/usr-data/photos';
$serverdir      = $absolutedir.$dir;
$filename       = array();

foreach($_FILES as $name => $value) {
    $json           = json_decode($_POST[$name.'_values']);
    $tmp            = explode(',',$json->data);
    $imgdata        = base64_decode($tmp[1]);

    $fileAry = explode('.',$json->name);
    $extension = strtolower(end( $fileAry ));

    $fname          = $card->id.'.'.$extension;

    $handle         = fopen($serverdir,'w');
    fwrite($handle, $imgdata);
    fclose($handle);

    $filename[]     = $fname;
}
```

I've tried using

> Icacls "F:\blog\public/usr-data/photos" /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)F

But no joy - still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This will work for Linux only. I'm keeping this answer in case anyone runs into the same problem on a Linux machine.

---

Try this:

```
 php artisan cache:clear 

 sudo chmod -R 777 app/storage 

 composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: You are correct, didn't notice the `lcacls` indicating that windows is being used. This solution will indeed work only for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up writing permissions on a `storage` and `public` folders and then all folders inside these ones. Use right click on a folder, go to `Properties` and change folder permissions.

http://m.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7

Comment: I've updated all the security profiles throughout the application and i'm still getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using file write, you can also use the Laravel filesystem storage class. Please try with the below given example.

```
$image represents the encoded image.
$Id represents the id of the user.


public function imageUpload($image, $Id)
   {
       //Decode base64 string to image
       $profile_image = 'image/jpeg;base64,' . $image;
       $new_data = explode(";", $image);
       $data = explode(",", $new_data[1]);
       $file = base64_decode($data[1]);
       $imageFileName = $Id . '.jpeg';
       $image_path = '/storage/' . $imageFileName;
       Storage::put($imageFileName, $file);
       return $image_path;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @suguna this worked however it only worked once? I get the error: Undefined offset: 1